# Iteratively Subset DataFrame based on Unique Times

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
                 Times  Values
0  05/10/2017 01:01:03       1
1  05/10/2017 01:05:00       2
2  05/10/2017 01:06:10       3
3  05/11/2017 08:25:20       4
4  05/11/2017 08:30:14       5
5  05/11/2017 08:30:35       6
```

I want to subset this DataFrame by the 'Time' column, by matching a partial string up to the hour.  For example, I want to subset using partial strings which contain "05/10/2017 01:" and "05/11/2017 08:" which breaks up the subsets into two new data frames:

```
>>> df1
                 Times  Values
0  05/10/2017 01:01:03       1
1  05/10/2017 01:05:00       2
2  05/10/2017 01:06:10       3
```

and

```
>>> df2
0  05/11/2017 08:25:20       4
1  05/11/2017 08:30:14       5
2  05/11/2017 08:30:35       6
```

Is it possible to make this subset iterative in Pandas, for multiple dates/times that similarly have the date/hour as the common identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, cast your `Times` column into a datetime format, and set it as the index:

```
df['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Times'])
df.set_index('Times', inplace = True)
```

Then use the groupby method, with a `TimeGrouper`:

```
g = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('h'))
```

`g` is an iterator that yields tuple pairs of times and sub-dataframes of those times. If you just want the sub-dfs, you can do `zip(*g)[1]`.

A caveat: the sub-dfs are indexed by the timestamp, and `pd.TimeGrouper` only works when the times are the index. If you want to have the timestamp as a column, you could instead do:

```
df['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Times'])
df['time_hour'] = df['Times'].dt.floor('1h')
g = df.groupby('time_hour')
```

Alternatively, you could just call `.reset_index()` on each of the dfs from the former method, but this will probably be much slower.

Comment: Ken, thanks for your solution.  A couple of questions: this may be obvious, but how do I index the new sub-dfs in g?  Additionally, how would you code change if i wanted to do a groupby down to the minute?  Thanks.

Comment: The sub-dfs are also dataframes, so you can index them in the same manner with `.loc`. For doing the groupby on minute, replace `'h'` with `'min'`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert Times to a hour period, groupby and then extract each group as a DF.

```
df1,df2=[g.drop('hour',1) for n,g in\
         df.assign(hour=pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Times)\
           .to_period('h')).groupby('hour')]

df1
Out[874]: 
                Times  Values
0 2017-05-10 01:01:03       1
1 2017-05-10 01:05:00       2
2 2017-05-10 01:06:10       3

df2
Out[875]: 
                Times  Values
3 2017-05-11 08:25:20       4
4 2017-05-11 08:30:14       5
5 2017-05-11 08:30:35       6
```

Comment: Hi Allen, this works, thanks.  Let's assume that all minutes are the same for df1 and separately, the minutes are the same for df2 (i.e. all 01:01 and all 08:30).  How would the above code change?  I'm taking the time now to better understand how your different functions are working together.  Cheers.

Comment: The groupby is using Year-Month-Day-Hour as the key the so the value of minutes don't matter. As long as they have the same key(Year-Month-Day-Hour), those records will be grouped into the same DF.

Comment: That makes sense.  I may want to subset down to the minute, though.  Is it possible to change the groupby to Year-Month-Day-Hour-Minute? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's possible. This will give you a minute breakdown: [g.drop('minute',1) for n,g in df.assign(minute=pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Times).to_period('T')).groupby('minute')]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the `Times` column is of type DateTime.
Second, set `times` column as index.
Third, use `between_time` method.

```
df['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Times'])
df.set_index('Times', inplace=True)

df1 = df.between_time('1:00:00', '1:59:59')
df2 = df.between_time('8:00:00', '8:59:59')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) type you can extract things like hours and days.

```
times = pd.to_datetime(df['Times'])
hours = times.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df1 = df[hours == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str[]` accessor to truncate the string representation of your date (you might have to cast `astype(str)` if your columns is a datetime and then use `groupby.groups` to access the dataframes as a dictionary where the keys are your truncated date values:

```
>>> df.groupby(df.Times.astype(str).str[0:13]).groups

{'2017-05-10 01': DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-10 01:01:03', '2017-05-10 01:05:00',
                '2017-05-10 01:06:10'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None),
 '2017-05-11 08': DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-11 08:25:20', '2017-05-11 08:30:14',
                '2017-05-11 08:30:35'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)}
```